# Why protocol buffer c++ library not reading binary objects properly

Tags: visual-c++, serialization, protocol-buffers

I created a binary file using a c++ program using protocol buffers. I had issues reading the binary file in my C# program, so I decided to write a small c++ program to test the reading.

My proto file is as follows

```
message TradeMessage {
required double timestamp = 1;
required string ric_code = 2;
required double price = 3;
required int64 size = 4;
required int64 AccumulatedVolume = 5;
}
```

When writing to protocol buffer, I first write the object type, then object length and the object itself.

```
coded_output->WriteLittleEndian32((int) ObjectType_Trade); 
coded_output->WriteLittleEndian32(trade.ByteSize()); 
trade.SerializeToCodedStream(coded_output);
```

Now, when I am trying to read the same file in my c++ program i see strange behavior.

My reading code is as follows:

```
coded_input->ReadLittleEndian32(&objtype);
coded_input->ReadLittleEndian32(&objlen);
tMsg.ParseFromCodedStream(coded_input);
cout << "Expected Size = " << objlen << endl;
cout<<" Trade message received for: "<< tMsg.ric_code() << endl;
cout << "TradeMessage Size = " << tMsg.ByteSize() << endl;
```

In this case, i get following output

```
Expected Size = 33
Trade message received for: .CSAP0104
TradeMessage Size = 42
```

**When I write to file, I write trade.ByteSize() as 33 bytes, but when I read the same object, the object ByteSize() is 42 bytes, which affects the rest of the data. I am not sure what is wrong in this. Please advice.**

Regards,
Alok

Comment: just to double check.. I compared the protocol buffer generated files in my reader and writer projects. The generated files are identical. So I guess, the file coding is different for some reason. I do not understand why it is different.

Comment: Any chance you can share your test values, just so I can check which is "more right" ?

Comment: also - minor point; if you wrote ([objtype] << 3) | 2 (as varint), then the byte-size (as varint), then the raw data, it would actually be a valid protobuf sequence itself, which can be useful - just sayin'

Comment: @MarcGravell can I mail you the binary data file? I am afraid there is no other way i can send you the file from here. I will make the changes regarding objtype (and some other fields) as you suggested.

Comment: @MarcGravell, dropped you an email just now.

Comment: I'm confused.... your binary file starts with  (decimal) 87,4,0,0 1,0,0,0 which is: objtype=1111, len=1... confused...

Comment: @MarcGravell, didn't see your last comment until today. It was hidden :(. Still new to the forum. Anyways, did I miss to mention about the file header before the objects start? I will send you the file header details in a separate email. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, i was doing a very silly mistake while creating the binary files. I did not open the file in binary mode when i wrote protobuf data to it causing it to add weird ascii characters in the middle. This caused an issue while reading the data using protobuf-net library. The issue is resolved here. Shouldn't have taken so long to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is guesswork, based on the above: when you use `ParseFromCodedStream`, you aren't actually limiting that to the `objlen` that you previously found; thus, if the stream contains any more data than this (i.e. that isn't the end of the file), the engine will try to keep reading to the EOF. You must cap the length to your expectation. I am not a C++ expert, so I can't offer direct guidance, but if this was C# (using protobuf-net):

```
objType = ProtoReader.DirectReadLittleEndianInt32(file);
len = ProtoReader.DirectReadLittleEndianInt32(file);

// assume GetObjectType returns typeof(TradeMessage) for our objType
Type type = GetObjectType(objType);
msg = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Deserialize(file, null, type, len, null);
```

Comment: apologies for late reply. I was travelling. SO i used your tip and put the specified the lengths while reading. Later I found this in the documentation itself. The idea is to push the length to read in the stream. c++ code is ok. But I still have the same issue while reading from my C# code :( using above code to read the objects, it still stops at the same location with following error ..  ProtoBuf.ProtoException: Incorrect number of bytes consumed
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type, Int32 length, SerializationContext context)

Comment: for c# version I was using following code  `TradeMessage tMsg = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<TradeMessage>(stream, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);`       This should have worked originally but it wasn't working. After this i wrote a test c++ program to check if generated file was ok. C3 version is still isn't working.

Comment: so looks like, even if I specify the length as the argument in function call `msg = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Deserialize(file, null, type, len, null);` internally, protobuf-net is not able to read **length** number of bytes. What could be the reason for this? c++ library is able to read the objects properly. Thanks.